# Get angular parent directive scope from child directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm trying to access the scope of the parent directive from a child directive.
Please see jsbin

http://jsbin.com/tipekajegage/3/edit

when I click the button I would like to the get value of prod.

var cpApp = angular.module('cpApp', []);

```
cpApp.directive('cpProduct', function(){
  var link = function (scope, element, attr) {
    console.log('scope.prod '+ scope.prod);
  };

  return {
    link: link,
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
  prod: '='
    }
  };
});

cpApp.directive('mediaButtons', [function(){

var template = 
'<button ng-click="addToFavoriteList()">get prod from parent</div>' + 
'</button>';

var controller = function($scope){
    var vm = this;
    $scope.addToFavoriteList = function(event){
       console.log($scope.$parent.prod);
      //GET PROD?
    };

};
return {
    template: template,
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: controller,
    scope: true
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the parent function as a require and assign it to local scope:

```
var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, cpProductCtrl) {
    scope.prod=cpProductCtrl.prod;
```

You also need to define a controller on the parent function like so:

```
controller: function($scope){
   this.prod=$scope.prod; 
}
```

Then you can call your clickHandler method like so:

```
console.log($scope.prod);
```

[Here is the JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tufurupuzebo/1/edit) In case I missed describing anything.

Comment: thanks that works, but there is no way to make it more generic where cpProduct is not required? I would maybe like to use the child directive inside another directive that would have scope.prod but is not cpProduct. Thanks

Comment: It's probably possible - Unfortunately I'm out of time to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

I restructured your code a bit, created a controller in your cpProduct directive and required it in the mediaButton to access its scope.

[See this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/TV2kZrY6gP6Xhvagzira/preview)

Comment: thank you. That works, seems to be the same idea as the previous answer.